# How Can I filter by file name in Automator by Shell Script?

Tags: shell, automator

I want to filtering by file name in Automator by Shell Script.
If I use this example it is work in correctly.

```
# Example (Filtering .wav files in ShellScript)
while read line; do
if expr "$line" : ".*.wav$" > /dev/null
then
    echo "$line" >&1
fi
done
```

How can I filter by the any keywords in filename.

(Example)

files in folder

- banana03284204
- banana39538539
- orange38053054
- orange35000382
- dog890938329
- cat349423942

I want to get files that contain "orange" from these files.

(Add Info)

The reason of I am using Shell Script, It is hard to success filtering files in NAS (Network Attached Storage)
For NAS files, Automator functions is failed.
I tried to add command to connect server in Automator.but failed.

Comment: `echo $line | grep -q orange` then `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then`

Comment: I success it by this way. Thanks a lot :)